# Как загрузить Layout в Activity или View из переменной типа String

Tags: android, xml, activity, view

Обычно внешний вид Activity или View загружается из файлов типа *.xml, вложенных в папку res/layout проекта. А как сделать, чтобы внешний вид загружался из произвольного текста, например из строкового поля базы данных, изменяя которое, пользователи приложения сами кастомизируют экраны и виджеты при помощи xml-разметки?

Comment: Интересный вопрос) И возможность есть какой-то более мене простой способ задать внешний вид Активити из строки, но боюсь у тебя возникнут проблемы с взаимодействием с этими объектами в коде.

Comment: @yno7 но при использовании XmlPullParser и загрузке layout'а из файла в папке assets точно такие же проблемы могут возникнуть. я понимаю, что кастомная xml разметка должна быть не с бухты-барахты, а соответствовать объекту, на который её натягивают. но только assets это тоже файлы, а мне нужно, чтобы такая разметка не хранилась изначально в приложении, а задавалась пользователем

Comment: Ну ты можешь подтягивать кастомный xml с сервера и записывать файл с ним в assets  или в любую другую папку своего апп. Ты же все равно не будешь при каждом старте грузить разметку, так как раз закэшируешь ее.

Comment: @yno7 а чем плохо грузить разметку при каждом старте? если в приложении есть несколько пользовательских экранов, и разметка от них хранится в базе данных

Comment: @yno7, _записывать файл с ним в assets или в любую другую папку своего апп_ - это в принципе не возможно, ресурсы упаковываются при сборке и что-то добавить/удалить/изменить без перепаковки приложения невозможно.

Comment: @ПавелСумароков, если `XmlPullParser` способен помочь в задаче, то почему бы не попытаться?

Comment: Я думал речь идет о подгрузке с сервера) Вообще не о том думал) (С assets точно, да)

Comment: @woesss а Вы уверены, что XmlPullParser позволяет inflate layout из произвольного текста, или он может работать исключительно с файлами?

Comment: Был бы уверен - написал бы ответ. Но пока ищете решение написать пару строк кода и проверить не сложно ведь? Я, наоборот, почти уверен что "коробочный" инфлейтер тут не помощник - скорее всего придётся самолично разбирать xml и по содержимому создавать вьюхи программно (т.е. писать свою реализацию инфлейтера). Проще всего будет пересмотреть задачу на html + `WebView` - тут я уверен, что всё решается "из коробки" и юзеру будет проще найти и освоить редактор `html`, чем разобраться с Андроид-макетами